# How to "Overflow" a value out of a certain range (like 30 - 100)

Tags: c++, math, struct

I have created a struct "Range" which contains two integers called min and max. I am trying to write a function which takes an integer and overflows it if it's out of range.
As an example, if I have a range `1-100` and I pass in `105` the return value should be `5`.

The code works fine when I try to overflow a value that is above the maximum but when the value is below the minimum unexpected behaviours happen and I can't find the correct formula.

This is the range struct I am using

```
struct Range
{
    int min;
    int max;
};
```

And this is the function declaration that I am using for the code below

```
int overflowRange(const Range &range, int n)
```

Here is the code when the value goes over range.max

```
if (n > range.max)
{
    double dist = static_cast<double>(n - range.max);
    double length = (range.max - range.min) + 1;
    //How many ranges away is n ?
    double numRanges = std::ceil(dist / length);

    return static_cast<int>(n - (length * numRanges));
}
```

And here is the code when the value goes below range.min

```
else if (n < range.min)    //n is the tested integer
{
    double dist = static_cast<double>(range.min - n);
    double length = (range.max - range.min);
    //How many ranges away is n ?
    int numRanges = static_cast<int>(dist / length);

    return static_cast<int>((range.min + length) - (dist - (length * numRanges)));
}
```

when `dist / length == 1` or `length * numRanges == dist` the returned value is sometimes out of range.

For example: If the range is `30-100` and the integer is `-40` I expect the return value to be `30` but it is actually `100`.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. Also, note that "unexpected behaviours happen" is not an observation but a (not very helpful) interpretation, see [ask]. As a new user, also take the [tour].

Comment: I described below the code what type of unexpected behaviours I was refering to, I will add small bits that help understand the code a bit better

Comment: @Matt, what's hesitation to create a [mcve]?

Comment: you can use the same formula, when you reverse the signs before and after, 40 is above -100 - -30. Its easier if you use `%`. Btw its really difficult to answer unless you provide a complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with integer math :

```
struct Range
{
    int min;
    int max;
};

int overflowRange(const Range &range, int n)
{
    int size = range.max - range.min;
    n -= range.min;
    n %= size;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        n += size;
    }
    n += range.min;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to stem from implicitly using the max as the datum when the value is below the min. If you change the return statement to the following, it should work.

```
return static_cast<int>(n + length*numRanges); // similar to above range case
```

You could simplify the logic by letting the math take care of the direction while you just take care of the datum.

```
int numRanges = 0;
double length = range.max - range.min; // you could make this a function on Range
if (n < range.min)
{
   double dist = n - range.min;
   numRanges = std::floor(dist/length);
}
else if (n > range.max)
{
   double dist = n - range.max;
   numRanges = std::ceil(dist/length);
}
else
{
   numRanges = 0;
}

return value - numRanges * length;
```

I tested this algorithm with [-40, 29, 30, 100, 101, 170] and the results were [30, 99, 30, 100, 31, 100], respectively.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, given the range 1 - 100, the return value should be 5 when you pass in a 105, you use 100 as a 0 in the range 101 - 200. It means the length of your range is 100 but not 99 because you actually overflow 100 numbers.
So here you use the length = (range.max - range.min) + 1 but not (range.max - range.min).

But when the pass-in value is below the minimum, what's your "expected behavior"? For example, given the range 30-100, which number should be returned when you pass in a 29? According to your exception "If the range is 30 - 100 and the integer is - 40 I expect the return value to be 30", then it should return 30+(29-(-40))=99 given a 29, which means that 30 and 100 represent the same number. Therefore, in this example you overflow 69 numbers but not 70, that means you use length = (range.max - range.min) here. Here conflict happens! You should not change the range length like this!